# Java HashMap.put() not working inside an invokeLater createAndShowGui method

Tags: java, swing, hashmap

I have a class which reads messages sent from a server, and the message could contain a command to create a gui from data inside the message, i.e. the message could be an Object {"show", data, guiData}.

The class has a private HashMap, to which new GUI's are added in the createAndShowGui method. But when I call .put() from inside said method, it doesn't work as I HashMap.get() returns null when called after the createAndShowGui method is called.

I've tried changing the hash map's modifier to final, but it doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
public class GuiController implements Runnable{

private final HashMap<String, JFrame> frameHashMap; //hashmap that contains the JFrame's

public GuiController(LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> inq, LinkedBlockingQueue<String> outq) {
    //constructor, loads blocking queue that messages are read off
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //recieves data from server, calls recieveMessage() with data object
}

private void receiveMessage(Object input) {
    if (c.qn(input)) return; //server api function to test if object is null
    final Object msg = input;
    final String message = (String)c.at(msg,0);
    final String name = (String)c.at(msg,1);
    final Object data;
    System.out.println(message + " " +name);

    switch (message){
        case "show":
            data = c.at(msg,2);
            if (!frameHashMap.containsKey(name)){ 
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        createAndShowGui(name, data, c.at(msg, 3), String.valueOf((char[])c.at(msg, 4)));
                    }
                });
            }

            for (String x: frameHashMap.keySet()) System.out.println(x + " -> " + frameHashMap.get(x));


            break;
        //other cases
    }
}


private void createAndShowGui(String name, Object data, Object gData, String title){
    System.out.println("Creating GUI with data at " + name + ", title: " + title +  "...");

    JFrame temp = new JFrame();

    temp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    temp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    temp.setTitle(title);
    temp.setContentPane(new KPanel(data, gData, outqueue)); //Subclass of JPanel for handling gui data
    temp.setName(name);

    this.frameHashMap.put(name, temp); //this doesn't work

}

}
```

The code prints out the println in the createAndShowGui method, but the for loop in the switch statement doesn't print anything out, and running .get(name) returns null.

EDIT: Sorry I haven't got more detail, this class is only started in a single new Thread from the main method. The code prints out the names of the input data and any println's in the KPanel constructors, the only thing that doesn't work is the .put() statement from what I can tell since. I'll do a push so you can download the source off github. Please note it's a private project and I haven't really gotten round to commenting it properly.

It's in fs_createandshow branch of https://github.com/adnang/JavaKGE

Comment: How do you know it does not work? Are you reading the content of the map from a different thread?

Comment: please whats your goal, because I'm sure that issue is in rest of code ...

Comment: Sorry, read the edited last sentence. I try to print out the keyset of the hashmap, and it doesn't print. It's at the bottom of the "show" case, @assylias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

[`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

instead of

[`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

your treading issue should be solved.  `invokeAndWait` will put the thread on the EDT, but also wait until the EDT has processed before continuing in the tread you called it in.  That way you guarentee that the `put(...)` has executed before the `get(...)`